# Mounting .img-file early in boot process

Tags: mount, ntfs, systemd, mountpoint

I have a rather unusual scenario. There is a ntfs-harddrive in my computer which I would like to mount, which isn't difficult on its own.

But there is an .img-file on said harddrive which I would like to mount at /usr.

Because this is an important system directory, it needs to be mounted very early on in the boot process.

An entry in the fstab - even in the right order - doesn't seem to fix this issue.

Systemd can do mounting as far as I know. What "RequiredBy"-Targets would I need to specify?

Thanks in advance

Markus